# How can I create named-instance of Microsoft SQL Server on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-16.04, sql-server-2016, named-instance, sql-default-instance

I used the official tutorial to create a default instance
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu

but now I want to create a named-instance and can't find how to do that

Comment: I wonder who downvotes questions about a *developer-only* preview that has more documentation in SO Docs than Microsoft's own docs site? It's definitely *not* an administration question - there are no administration tools available yet!

Comment: Can you check the parameters of `sqlservr-setup` ? `apt-get install` only installs the package. Assuming this is implemented, the functionality should be available through `sqlservr-setup`

Comment: `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr-setup --help
Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R) Setup

This utility helps configure Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R).
Without options this tool will perform interactive configuration.

Usage: sqlservr-setup [--help] [--accept-eula] [--reset-sa-password]
                      [--set-sa-password] [--start-service]
                      [--enable-service] [--stop-service]
                      [--disable-service]

Options:
  --help                  This help screen.

  --accept-eula           Accept EULA
`

Comment: `
  --reset-sa-password     Reset SA password interactively
  --set-sa-password       Set SA password from SA_PASSWORD environment variable

  --start-service         Start the SQL Server service
  --enable-service        Enable the SQL Server service to start at boot

  --stop-service          Stop the SQL Server service
  --disable-service       Disable the SQL Server service from starting at boot
`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I added the help of this command from the termainal. can't see any relevant config. should I search in other place?

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server on Linux doesn't support the notion of "multi-instance", so there are no named instances on Linux.

You can see that its Windows only feature here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/work-with-multiple-versions-and-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15